# There is a weird part at proof of theorem about limits of composition function

Tags: calculus, limits

When $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to a}g(x)=b$
$\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(g(x))=f(b)$

[proof]

$f$ is continuous at $b$, therefore
For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ satisfies
$0<|y-b|<\delta_1 \implies |f(y)-f(b)|<\epsilon$

$\lim \limits_{x \to a}g(x)=b$, therefore
For all $\delta_1>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ satisfies
$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |g(x)-b|<\delta_1$

From above for all $\epsilon$>0, there exists $\delta>0$ satisfies
$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(g(x))-f(b)|<\epsilon$

At the last part of the proof, $|g(x)-b|<\delta_1 \implies 0<|y-b|<\delta_1(g(x)=y)$
But there is no "$0<$" in the left part. $a<10 \implies 0<a<10$ is not true.
 Is there a missing part of my thinking?

Comment: It's an absolute value, so it is always $\ge 0$.

Comment: @MarcoVergamini but how about $=0$ ? That matters.

Comment: The usualk formulation for "continuous at $b$" is: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ that satisfies $|y-b|<\delta_1\implies |f(y)-f(b)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $|f(g(x))-f(b)| <\epsilon$ is obviuosly true when  $g(x)=b$. When $g(x) \neq b$ the inequalities you have obtained imply $|f(g(x))-f(b)| <\epsilon$ provided $0<|x-a| <\delta$.

Comment: Very nice and simple explanation